# I am getting error when i try to insert an image using UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql

Please can any one tell me what is wrong in this sql command?

```
UPDATE map1 
SET image = LOAD_FIELD('C/:a(1).jpg')
WHERE id = 1
```

this is the error which i get when i try to run it on (PHPMyadmin)..

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '/:a(1).jpg'')

Comment: Did you mean to use `LOAD_FILE`?

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: i didn't mean to use LOAD_FILE, i am a beginner and i found others loading images this way...
I had a table then i ALTERed it and added new column for images. So i want to update the existing fields (rows) and add images in this new column.
i need to do this using any possible way :)

Comment: I am using Windows 10